# How does chewy treats promote clean teeth and gums

Tags: dogs, diet

I bought edible Nubz chewy treats and on the bag it says it promotes healthy gums and teeth. How exactly does it do this? Wouldn't it just stain the teeth more? Also, is this actually healthy - should this only be kept as treats or could it be used as a meal?

**Ingredients:** wheat starch, glycerin, powdered cellulose,dried chicken, lecithin, natural flavor and natural bacon flavor.

**Guaranteed Analysis:** crude protein 2%, crude fat 0.5%, crude fiver 8% and moisture 15%

Picture of the treat:
[image]

Comment: Can you include the ingredients of this product and a pic of one of the treats please?

Comment: I've updated the post.

Comment: If you can take a pic so we can see the texture - it would also be helpful. Thanks

Comment: they dont unless the manufactorer can dokument it and then it is marked on the pakage as dokumented effect on the package.you might contact the manufactorer and ask them to send you the dokumentation,if they dont send it to you you have the answer to your question.

Comment: I see @trondhansen . But could it be unhealthy? I don't think so, just because dog food is more regulated it seems than human food is.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I've attached the picture

Comment: when one reads the list of content the largest amount of an ingredient  is mentioned first so it is more wheat than it is glycerin and more glycerin than it is cellulose and so on,it is not unhealthy if you dont give it too often as in once or twice a day but not more then this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "nubs" or "rounded spike things" on this treat is contributing the most when it comes to THIS SPECIFIC TREAT. The idea is that while your dog chews on it, the nubs rub up against and gently massage the teeth, gums and cheeks. The different height between the grooves of the nubs and smooth parts of this bone will help reach parts of the teeth that a 100% smooth bone won't (imagine dog biting into it, teeth landing in between 2 nubs, dog gets more surface area of the treat rubbing on teeth than if it were just smooth or flat).

Also, powdered cellulose is, in my opinion an "incredibly low quality ingredient" but it is as least good for one thing, it's an emulsifier. It is a low grade fiber source that is unnecessary for digestion if your dog is on a well balanced diet BUT it does add to the texture and tartar scrape-ability of this bone. This bone sounds like a tasty treat version of a "dental bone", maybe one I'd only recommend as a go-to last resort over other options (not wanting or able to brush your dogs teeth BUT your dog is also extremely picky and at least you can get your dog to chew on this?). It is definitely a "treat" not a necessary dietary supplement.

Other ingredients listed are not known as being "good for teeth" but a lot of extra ingredients are added to dental treats, and the treat still serves it's purpose anyways. Wheat starch is specifically bad for tartar build up, though.

Comment: Hmm, so it's actually doing as much as bad as good since it has wheat tartar? lol